# Nginx - is it possible to redirect to different https servers based on the servername?

Tags: nginx, http-redirect

Currently , I am redirecting http request this way :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name emberhub.me www.emberhub.me test.emberhub.me;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


# HTTPS server static html
#
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name emberhub.me www.emberhub.me;

    root html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    ssl on;
    ....
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;


# HTTPS server proxy Node.js app
#
server {
    listen 444 ssl;
    server_name test.emberhub.me;

    ssl on;
    ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

When user request :
http://emberhub.me  or http://www.emberhub.me , he is correctly redirected to  https://emberhub.me or https://www.emberhub.me  ( on default port 443 )

But when user request:
http://test.emberhub.me , he is redirected ALSO to port 443 and get the static html page, not to the node.js app

If the user request it with the port 444 
http://test.emberhub.me:444, then he is correctly proxied to the node.js app...

Is there a way to filter the request based on the server_name and redirect it with the correct SSL port ? or is there another better way to perform these redirections ?

thanks for feedback

UPDATE 1 :

I tried to change the server declaratives , as following, but I still get the same issue ...  http://test.emberhub.me , is always redirected to port 443

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name emberhub.me;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
#        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name www.emberhub.me;
    return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
#        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name test.emberhub.me;
    return 301 https://$host:444$request_uri;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I updated the default config to

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name test.emberhub.me;
    return 301 https://$host:444$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name  emberhub.me  www.emberhub.me;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

using `curl -v` everything runs fine ...

```
 $ curl -v http://emberhub.me
 * Rebuilt URL to: http://emberhub.me/
 ...
 < Connection: keep-alive
 < Location: https://emberhub.me/
 ...
 Connection #0 to host emberhub.me left intact

$ curl -v http://www.emberhub.me
...
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.emberhub.me/
Connection #0 to host www.emberhub.me left intact

curl -v http://test.emberhub.me
Rebuilt URL to: http://test.emberhub.me/
...
< Location: https://test.emberhub.me:444/
Connection #0 to host test.emberhub.me left intact
```

BUT requesting http://test.emberhub.me in the browser display https://test.emberhub.me  on port 443 ...

Comment: separate config for each domain/site rather than combining them all in to one as you've got conflicting server_name directives so its catching all on the first server block. so do one config for emberhub.me and www.emberhub.me as they're effectively the same and do a separate config for test.emberhub.me I've got example configs for this on my server at home but not here i'm afraid. also google correctly configuring nginx for ssl to make it secure.

Comment: I tried to separate the config but no way ...

Comment: Sorry old topic. But the problem is probably your browser cache messing with ip's directives ;) try using incognito.

Answer (score 0):

If you need different behavior on that server then make a separate config for it:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.emberhub.me;
  return 301 https://$host:444$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I understand , however in this case I get a duplicate listen option :

    duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test

Comment: @erwin did you removed the domain from the first server? also you probably do not need separate listen for ipv6

Comment: You can have as many server {} blocks as you want with duplicate listen directives. Nginx will just evaluate them to see which one matches based on the server_name. The two gotchas are:  HTTPS on clients that don't support SNI (so have to be careful). Additionally if you have something doing, say, "listen 80" and another doing "listen 127.0.0.1:80", the the more specific one will win, and the hosts just listening on "listen 80" won't be visible on localhost.

Comment: I updated the server declaratives , when I curl it out , it seems to be fine , I get the correct returns (  Location: https://www.emberhub.me/,  Location: https://emberhub.me/ , Location: https://test.emberhub.me:444/ ) but it's not fine using the browser ...  does the proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080  in the 444 ssl block is 'badly' doing some weird things ?

Comment: @erwin that is because you have Strict-Transport-Security set - when set, browser will go to 443 on the second visit, ignoring 80 port, even when explicitly set to `http://..:80`

Comment: thanks a lot for this info... I'll read more about it by tomorrow ... being late overthere ;-)

Comment: I commented out the add_header Transport and restarted nginx , but no change ... I cannot get the http://test.emberhub.me redirected to  the node.js app ... on

Comment: @erwin commenting out is not enough - you need to reset it by serving with `max-age=0` at 443